# How to get latest version of git?

Tags: ubuntu, installation, git, apt, version

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, need to install GIT 1.9.5 or above. I did `sudo apt-get install git` then ran  `git --version` and it shows I currently have 1.9.1 installed. Git download url shows latest version is 2.3.0.

Why did it not download 2.3.0 and how can I get a version 1.9.5 or above?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Git stable releases PPA has the most current stable version of Git for Ubuntu. Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:git-core/ppa  
sudo apt update  
sudo apt install git
```

These commands will install git 2.3.0 (the current stable version of Git) on your system for all currently supported Ubuntu releases. A short time after a new version of git is released, git from ppa:git-core/ppa is updated to the latest version

Comment: Oh my :D I am so happy, thank you sir, got tears on my eyes. I spent many hours trying to get the latest version. I am a big n00b to linux. Thank you very much :D By the way, do you have any basics on linux links? Or maybe I should just read the ubuntu manual? I really need to become very good and comfortable with linux fast.

Comment: 1. [Guia Introdutório do Ubuntu](http://wiki.ubuntu-br.org/GuiaIntrodutorio) 2. [Documentação do Ubuntu Brasil](http://wiki.ubuntu-br.org/Documentacao) 3. [Getting Started with Ubuntu 14.04](https://ubuntu-manual.org/)

Answer (score -1):

If git is already installed on your system, the last step should be:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```